# Spring Boot:Unable to load cache item and ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

AutoConfiguration:

```
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@Bean
open fun protobufHttpMessageConverter(): ProtobufHttpMessageConverter {
    return ProtobufHttpMessageConverter()
}
```

Means: if current runtime environment is `Web Application`, `protobufHttpMessageConverter` will be created, else ignored.

But when I run project without `Web Environment`, an error occured:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.converter.protobuf.ProtobufHttpMessageConverter
```

Of course not exist `ProtobufHttpMessageConverter` class, current environment is not `Web`, I'm confused why and how `@ConditionalOnWebApplication` doesn't work?

Comment: For specific library, use [@ConditionalOnClass](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnClass.html) instead of `@ConditionalOnWebApplication`.

Comment: @tan9 still same error

Comment: Because the class is still loaded and thus is needs the dependencies. That is the reason why many of the spring boot auto configuration classes have internal config classes to delay the loading of optional classes. If you want to use `@ConditionalOnClass` use it with a `String` for the classname rather then the actual class (as that would require the class again to be available at runtime).

Comment: @M.Deinum Same error even use `@ConditionalOnClass(name = "className"`)

Comment: The conditional needs to go on the top level class, then the class needs to have an embedded static class containing the class. That way loading the class will be delayed, else you still need it because it is part of the method signature.